# Desmos assign operator ($\rightarrow$) assigning multiple times without click manually

Tags: math-software, desmos

How do I assign a variabel automatically for n-times without clicking it n-times?

I have this statement that I must click the red circled button in picture to assign updated value for variabel $a$:
[image]

where initially: $a=[3]$

Then yes its worked, the $a$ value will updated after I click the button to:
$a=[3,2.98]$

This is problem for me if I want repeat multiple times like 100 times due to manually click it therefore it will slow (depends on my fingers) .

So I expect I can iterate (assigning) it automatically to the 100 times.

Here is full graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8rovvdndnr

Comment: Desmos' [ticker](https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407725009165-Actions) feature automatically does just this. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tsufaopes3)'s an example using an updated version of your graph. To start, just click the metronome icon in the top left of the formula list.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Graviton now I can extend your graph version.

While your answer was only introducing *ticker* feature, now I can solve my problem.

My problem is limited to the `100 iterrations`. So how do I do it?

Just define expression conditional action with curly bracket desmos syntax in variabel $I$ that is... do action $A$ (appending list $a$ then increment $i+=1$) while $i < 100$.

Since I don't need delay, so I set to `0ms`.

Then to run the program just click the metronome ticks buttons.
Here is full version of graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9fwflxdhdc

About my mathematical problem, it's just simple computational problem where the application is commonly in Machine Learning or Artificial Inteligent, that is [Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). Where:

- $f(x)$ is function.
- $l(x,r)$ is learning function with parameter $r$ is `learning rate`.

Since gradient descent need previous output of $l(x,r)$ and desmos currently doesn't support recursive $l(l(l(3,r),r),r)$, you can use this solution to compute recursive function.